# Spring cloud config and Vault Integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-vault

I'm trying to read secret values using spring vault. All the properties for client application is stored in github and spring config server is used to access the properties. When I add the vault configuration to client application bootstrap.yml as below, the values are read properly.

```
bootstrap.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: client-app
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://config-server:8080
    vault:
      enabled: true
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: 12345
        secret-id: 12345
        role: pres-read
        app-role-path: approle
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secrets
        application-name: client-app
      uri: https://vault/
```

application.yml in config server

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git :
          uri: https://github/repo.git
          username: abc
          password: pass
          refreshRate: 300
```

Based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/docs/current/reference/html/config-data.html#vault.configdata , it should be possible to load the vault config from properties yml in github. But if i move the above vault config to my client-app.yml in github, the properties are not read from the vault. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The docs mention spring.config.import, did you do that?

Comment: @spencergibb yes. I added config.import: vault://  in the client-app.yml. It didn't work

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it didn't work?"

Comment: @spencergibb. The client-app is not able to read the properties from vault, even with "config.import: vault://" added

Comment: I even tried adding the vault properties to config-server yml as well.  It didn't help either.

Comment: If it can't read it there would be en error or something in the logs